# How to create a Facebook login flow to get access token without hosting the web application (On local machine/ Netbeans Apache Tomcat Server)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want to create a Facebook login page for my web application developed on Netbeans. I followed the tutorial given on Facebook website ([Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web)) I copied the HTML code provided there. My site URL of the App is set to http://localhost.com/ . I have also configured the hosts file of my windows system( Added an entry "127.0.0.1   localhost.com").

Now, upon running this code either through Netbeans or by simply running the code in the browser through a html file,  I'm not getting any response from Facebook. The webpage remains blank. Please tell if there is anything that I'm missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Facebook login code:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '{My App ID}', // I have entered my APP-ID here
status     : true, 
cookie     : true, 
xfbml      : true,  
oauth      : true
});
FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

if (response.status === 'connected') {

  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

  FB.login();
} else {

  FB.login();
}
});
};


(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));


function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
});
 }
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Edit: It seems Facebook no longer supports JS SDK calls made from a local file, the script has to be run on a file with an http:// or https:// URI. So, I changed the js.src assignment to "js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";".

But now I'm getting an error as "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: What protocol do you use? `file:////` or `http` because the 1st it won't wont since Facebook JS is loaded basing on the protocol you're currently browsing that file on ` js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`

Comment: Yeah, I just corrected that error. Thank you. But now I'm getting an error as "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: It seems there is a problem in the App site URL.

Comment: Yes, go to you App dashboard and change Site URL to the exact URL where your app root/URL is